# Wants to get Check boxes with labels

Tags: java, swing

In this code, I'm adding the data from Database. I want to set cell renderer with a label. But if I run this code I got only check box.

```
try {
        List<Group> listgrChild = grMgmtModel.performList();

        for (final Group group : listgrChild) {
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0)
                    .setCellRenderer(new TableCellRenderer() {
                        // the method gives the component like whome the
                        // cell must
                        // be rendered
                        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
                                JTable table, Object value,
                                boolean isSelected, boolean isFocused,
                                int row, int col) {
                            boolean marked = new Boolean(String
                                    .valueOf(value));
                            JCheckBox rendererComponent = new JCheckBox();
                            if (marked) {
                                rendererComponent.setSelected(true);
                            }
                            return rendererComponent;
                        }
                    });
            tbModel.addRow(new Object[] { group.getGroupName() });
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean `rendererComponent.setText("Hello world")`?

Comment: You'll find that this is very inefficient and will cause the JM to allocate a lot of memory over a short period of time, repeatedly. Instead, create the check box just once and keep changing its properties

Comment: renderComponent.setText("Hello"); is giving only last value. in 2 times

Answer (score 1):

You comment, "`renderComponent.setText("Hello")` is giving only last value."

Verify that your `TableModel` has individual storage for each row's check box state and label value. In this [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table), the class `Value` holds the relevant data:

```
private static class Value implements Comparable<Value> {
    private Boolean selected;
    private Double value;
    …
}
```

The corresponding `TableModel` manages a `List<Value>` and the required [renderer and editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) use the data from each `Value` instance accordingly. As an aside, `Value` implements the `Comparable` interface for convenience in [sorting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).